# React Bootstrap doesn't hide nav items on collapse?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HALY.png)

[image of issue click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw8pR.jpg)

I am using React Bootstrap and my nav bar doesn't hide the nav items when collapsed but instead shows the burger menu and the nav items beside it. However when the burger menu is click it shows the list of items as it should. Is there a way to hide the items before the menu is clicked?

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./components/Home"
import About from "./components/About";
import Services from "./components/Services.js";
import Careers from "./components/Careers";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";

function App() {
  return (
  
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="sm" fixed="top">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav'/>
          <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'/>
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about" >About</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/services">Services</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/careers">Careers</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/contact">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          <Navbar.Collapse/>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
  <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
        <Route path="/services" element={<Services/>}/>
        <Route path="/careers" element={<Careers/>}/>
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  
  );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSX is not correct, the Navbar.Collapse should contain your navbar, otherwise there's nothing to collapse. Here you're autoclosing both Navbar.Collapse elements

It should look like this:

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="sm" fixed="top">
    <Container>
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav'/>
      <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
         <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about" >About</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/services">Services</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/careers">Careers</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/contact">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
```